# Jquery Calendar is not opening with angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, datepicker

Please help, our Jquery calendar is not opening after using angular js on it. I am new to angular Js. Please help.
You can find the issue here on this url 
 [Click here](http://testserver.sodiztechnologies.com/code/)

Please select Import Exposure from Select Box to get the another box having the problem textbox where calendar should popup.

Also you can download the code here, download code.zip here on 
[click here](http://testserver.sodiztechnologies.com)

Please watch this snapshot to know about the problem[image]

I want calendar to open like this. Please watch we want calendar to open like this.
[image]

Thanks, Please help!

Comment: can you replicate the same  on plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution with your code is here if you acceppt please vote up ;)

[link to calendar](http://www.filedropper.com/calenadar)

in short your app.js should look like that:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', []);

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('ExposureController', ExposureController)
        .directive('datepicker', datepicker);

    function ExposureController($scope) {

    }

    function datepicker() {
        return {
            restrict: "EAC",
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                var updateModel = function(dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                };
                var options = {
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    onSelect: function(dateText) {
                        updateModel(dateText);
                    }
                };
                elem.datepicker(options);
            }
        };
    }
}());
```

the best for you it will be use angular directive to fire jquery plugin